# Using the current group_by as an alias for select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
      SUM(queries), 
      unique_identifier 
FROM table_name GROUP BY unique_identifier
```

Is there a way to get the current group by value as the alias of the SUM()

Example:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(queries) AS unique_identifier 
FROM table_name GROUP BY unique_identifier
```

or

```
SELECT 
     SUM(queries) AS unique_alias 
FROM table_name GROUP BY unique_identifier AS unique_alias
```

Expected result should be:

```
SUM(), unique_alias_1
SUM(), unique_alias_2
SUM(), unique_alias_3
```

Comment: There is no problem with naming the alias `unique_identifier`, but perhaps that's not what you want? Do you have an example of what the result would look like?

Comment: I added an example, which helps me understand that this might not be possible without just doing more work on the server side.

Comment: Does the values like `unique_alias_1` come from the `unique_identifier` field? You haven't shown what names you expect the columns to have, which is what the aliases would be used for.